# BlackBerry10 application is not signing properly due to keystore issue

Tags: blackberry-10, signing

I am creating a sencha application and i want to run it on BB10 device. I have requested for  signin Key files from BlackBerry and  received two .csj registration files by mail . For signing my application i am using this command :

**blackberry-signer –register –csjpin 01234567 –storepass mcube F:\BB10Key-28Feb\client-PBDT-1975809.csj F:\BB10Key-28Feb\client-RDK-1975809.csj**

It gives error :

**"Error: Keystore load: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big."**

I don't have any idea about it that how it will be solve .

Comment: what development platform are you using. NDK, Android Run time or HTML, etc.

Comment: I am using HTML development Platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.com

I think you are passing wrong files to the signer.

```
blackberry-signer -register -csjpin <csj pin> 
-storepass <KeystorePassword> <client-RDK-xxxxxx.csj file> 
<client-PBDT-xxxxx.csj file>
```

I see you are passing PBDT key first in place of RDK key.

Your code would be like this (please do not copy paste this command when signing yourself as this is for demo puposes only)

```
blackberry-signer –register –csjpin 01234567 –storepass mcube F:\BB10Key-28Feb\client-RDK-1975809.csj F:\BB10Key-28Feb\client-PBDT-1975809.csj
```

You should pass RDK key then PBDT key. Modify your bar signer tool command and run again with correct parameters. For more info visit [Set up for signing BlackBerry 10 apps](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_bb10_apps_2008396_11.html) and [Signing your BlackBerry 10 application](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_your_bb10_app_2008398_11.html).

If this solves your problem, check this as answer.